# Need cakephp's Auth component configuration details?

Tags: php, cakephp

Would someone pease explain this function to me in its entirety? i.e what the function beforeFilter does and what each line is doing. Thanks.

```
function beforeFilter()
{
    //Configure AuthComponent
    $this->Auth->authorize = 'actions';
    $this->Auth->actionPath = 'controllers/';

    $this->Auth->loginAction = array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login');
    $this->Auth->loginRedirect = array('controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'add');

    $this->Auth->logoutRedirect = array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login');
}
```

Comment: It says what it does in the comment. It configures the AuthComponent. Nothing magical. It's a simple assignment of values to properties. Please clarify your question to point out what exactly you don't understand about it.

Comment: *(reference)* http://api.cakephp.org/class/auth-component

Comment: That's one very bad question title.

Comment: make your question title more specific, i fixed it for you :)

Answer (score 4):

Documented Code

```
// `beforeFilter()` gets executed before the request forwarded to `action`
function beforeFilter() {
    //Configure AuthComponent
    // read http://book.cakephp.org/complete/1250/Authentication#authorize-1275
    $this->Auth->authorize = 'actions';

    // read http://book.cakephp.org/complete/1250/Authentication#actionPath-1279
    $this->Auth->actionPath = 'controllers/';

    // tells the Auth component the location of login action
    $this->Auth->loginAction = array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login');

    // tells the Auth component where to redirect after successful login
    $this->Auth->loginRedirect = array('controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'add');

    // tells the Auth component where to redirect after logout
    $this->Auth->logoutRedirect = array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login'); }
```

Your must read this http://book.cakephp.org/complete/1250/Authentication

Comment: Why wouldn't things like the login and logout redirect be inside in the login and logout functions of your users controller?

Comment: They wont actually **do** redirect, they just tell them where to redirect after success. this is usually done in `app_controller.php` so that configuration is same in all actions. You may also override them anywhere within your actions (*but usually you need not to*).